# Linear approximation of matrix norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Given a square matrix $X=[x_1...x_N]$, and can be vectorized by $y=vec(X)=[x_1^T ... x_N^T]^T$

Is there any linear function can approximate $|| X ||$ (any matrix norm is okay) by using $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess you might want to take a look at any "elementwise" norm:

$$\|X\|_p=\left(\sum_{i,j}\left|X_{ij}\right|^p\right)^{1/p}$$

You can always use piecewise linear approximations of this but unless you take $p=1$, it won't really be linear. If you take $p=1$ you will have a huge norm and you might want to tune this down a little. That way, you can make you "own" norm like this one for instance:

$$\|X\|=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j}\left|X_{ij}\right|$$

It is indeed a norm because for any $X,Y\in\Bbb{K}^{N\times N}$:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\|X\|\geq0 \\ \|X\|=0 & \mbox{iff} & X=0 \\ \forall\lambda\in\Bbb{K},\space\|\lambda X\|=|\lambda|\|X\| \\ \|X+Y\|\leq\|X\|+\|Y\|\end{array}\right.$$

**Proof:**

- $\forall (i,j)\in[1,N]^2,\space |X_{ij}|\geq0 \Rightarrow \sum_{i,j}\left|X_{ij}\right|\geq0\Rightarrow \|X\|\geq0$
- $(\|X\|=0)\Leftrightarrow(\sum_{i,j}\left|X_{ij}\right|=0)$ : a sum of positive values equals $0$ iff all those values equal $0$. So $(\|X\|=0)\Leftrightarrow(\forall(i,j)\in[1,N]^2,\space |X_{ij}|=0)\Leftrightarrow(\forall(i,j)\in[1,N]^2,\space X_{ij}=0)\Leftrightarrow(X=0)$
- Let $\lambda\in\Bbb{K}$, then $\|\lambda X\|_p=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j}\left|\lambda X_{ij}\right|=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j}|\lambda| |X_{ij}|=|\lambda|\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j}|X_{ij}|=|\lambda|\|X\|$
- $\|X+Y\|=\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i,j}|X_{ij}+Y_{ij}|$. And $\forall(i,j)\in[1,N]^2,\space |X_{ij}+Y_{ij}|\leq|X_{ij}|+|Y_{ij}|$. So $\sum_{i,j}|X_{ij}+Y_{ij}|\leq\sum_{i,j}|X_{ij}|+\sum_{i,j}|Y_{ij}|$. Thus $\|X+Y\|\leq\|X\|+\|Y\|$

Now if you want to write it using your $y$ vector (the flattened matrix $X$):

$$\|X\|=\frac{1}{N^2}\|y\|_1$$

Or if you denote $y_{abs}=[|y_1|\cdots|y_{N^2}|]^T$ and $\vec{1}=[1\cdots1]$ (of size $N^2$) then:

$$\|X\|=\left(\frac{\vec{1}}{N^2}\right)\cdot y_{abs}$$

**EDIT:**

It also works if you replace $N^2$ by any positive non-zero constant ;)